# нужно задать число в сессию после чего число из списка должно быть не активным

Tags: php, html, css3

Краткое условие

1. Компьютер должен загадать число от 1 до 10; 2. Варианты ответов выводим циклом через select 3. Даем три попытки, и каждый раз делаем не активную предыдущую попытку;

   `

   ```
    <form method='get'>
    <p>Выберите число от "1" до "10" </p>

    <select name="number_select">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Угадали">

    <p> <?=$messege?>
    </p>

    </form>
   ```

   вот код php
   //
   общее количество попыток
   $number_attempts= 3;
   //
   рандомное число
   $number_rand = rand(1, 10);
   //
   сколько попыток у нас осталось
   $attempts = 3;
   // Объявление сообщения
   $messege="
   Начало игры";
   // подключение форм получения числа, которое избрал пользователь
   $number_select=0;

   //
   Берем с сессии количество попыток, которое у нас осталось
   if (isset($_SESSION['attempts'])){
   $attempts=$_SESSION['attempts'];

   }
   //
   Проверяем наличие выбранного числа переданного из формы
   if(isset($_GET['number_select'])){
   $number_select=$_GET['number_select'];

   ```
    // Записываем в сессию загаданное число
   ```

   $_SESSION['number_select']=$number_select;
   if($number_select)
   // Приравниваем наше принятое значение со случайным числомПриравниваем наше принятое значение со случайным числом
   if($number_rand==$number_select){
   $messege="
   Поздравляем! Вы выиграли!";

   ```
    }else {
        $messege="вы не выиграли"; 

    }
   ```

   }
   //уменьшаем количество попыток, если закончилось записываемое в сессию начальное значение (максимального количества попыток)
   if($attempts>0){
   $attempts--;
   $_SESSION['attempts']=$attempts;
   }else {
   //
   Дописываем сообщение
   $messege.="Попытки закончились";
   $_SESSION['attempts']=$number_attempts;
   }

   // for($j=$number_attempts; $j>0; $j-=1){
   //     echo "

   осталось попыток:$j

   ";

   // }

   ?>`

застрявшая на этапе после записи загаданного числа сделать его не активным в списке

Буду благодарна за советы!

Answer (score 0):

нашла ответ. изменив структуру и несколько откорректировав в коде и вот результат`

```
<?php
session_start();

$number_attempts = 3;
$number_rand = rand(1, 10);
$attempts = 3;
$messege = "Начало игры";
$number_select = 0;
$button_text = "
Угадать";

if (isset($_SESSION['attempts'])) {
    $attempts = $_SESSION['attempts'];
}

if (isset($_GET['number_select'])) {
    $number_select = $_GET['number_select'];

    $_SESSION['number_select'] = $number_select;
    if ($number_select == $number_rand) {
        $messege = "
Поздравляем! Вы выиграли!";
        $attempts = $number_attempts;
        $button_text = "
Новая игра";
    } else {
        $messege = "Ви не виграли";
    }
}

if ($attempts > 0) {
    $attempts--;
    $_SESSION['attempts'] = $attempts;
} else {
    $messege .= " 
Попытки закончились";
    $_SESSION['attempts'] = $number_attempts;
    $button_text = "Новая игра";
}

$available_numbers = range(1, 10);

if ($number_select) {
    $key = array_search($number_select, $available_numbers);
    if ($key !== false) {
        unset($available_numbers[$key]);
    }
}
?>


<form method='get'>
    <p>
Выберите число от "1" до "10"</p>
    <select name="number_select">
        <?php
        $selected_number = (int)$number_select; 

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            if ($selected_number === $i) {
                continue;
            }

            echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="<?=$button_text?>">
    <p> <?=$messege?></p>
</form>`
```